# Force tablet to use xhdpi resources

Tags: android, xml

I'm working on an application and i've provided all the resources from ldpi to xhdpi, but some tablets use hdpi (or tvdpi in the case of the nexus 7 i'm testing on) so when i open the app on a tablet everything is small, i would like to force them to use the xhdpi resources how can i do that?

I don't want to create separate files just for the tablets or the size of the app would increase, the xhdpi resources would work fine

[image]

On the phones everything is displaying properly, the tablets are the problem because they take small resolution assets for their big screens, so the actual size in inch( 4cm, measured with a ruler) is correct, but they actually look small making the overall design incorrect

Comment: unfortunately I don't think you get any control over it at the Application level. AFAIK the density "bucket" is hardcoded into the device, and it will always take the resources that match its hardcoded density type if they are available.

Answer (score 5):

Usually, downscaling is the best option (as opposed to up-scaling).
If your images don't degrade or loose information when they are downscaled, put the 2x version of your images in the *res/drawable-**xhdpi*** folder. Android will scale these images down appropriately on lower density devices.

E.g. if you put a 64x64 pixel jpg/png in *res/drawable-xhdpi*, Android will show it as a 32x32 pixel on mdpi devices, as a 48x48 pixel image on hdpi devices and as a 64x64 pixel image on xhdpi devices.

If downscaling your images would deteriorate your them (e.g. you have 1 pixel lines in your image that would disappear when scaled down), then the only option is to add the variations of your images in the drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi, etc. directories.

**Update after comments:**

You'd want to have your images appear larger on **larger** screens (not on higher **density** screens). You could do this by still putting your images in the drawable-xhdpi folder only, but then do this:

E.g. you'll have this layout in res/layout with an ImageView that shows one of your images:

**res/drawable-xhdpi/one_of_my_images.png**

**res/layout/somelayout.xml**

```
....
<ImageView 
    android:layout_height="@dimen/image_height"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/image_width"
    android:src="@drawable/one_of_my_images"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    ....
    />
```

**res/values/dimens.xml**

```
....
<dimen name="image_height">100dip</dimen>
<dimen name="image_width">150dip</dimen>
....
```

**res/values-large/dimens.xml**

```
....
<dimen name="image_height">150dip</dimen>
<dimen name="image_width">225dip</dimen>
....
```

**res/values-xlarge/dimens.xml**

```
....
<dimen name="image_height">200dip</dimen>
<dimen name="image_width">300dip</dimen>
....
```

As you can see, the larger the screen, the larger (in dip and therefore in inches) the image.
You can experiment with different values for image_height and image_width in dimens.xml in res/values-xlarge-hdpi, res/values-xlarge-xhdpi, etc and see what looks best.

**Update 2 after comments:**
If you want your own 'custom' scheme of loading the appropriate resource, put them id res/drawable-nodpi:
E.g
res/drawable-nodpi/one_of_my_images_normal.png
res/drawable-nodpi/one_of_my_images_large.png
res/drawable-nodpi/one_of_my_images_xlarge.png

Then put in the appropriate drawable dir (res/drawable/, res/drawable-large, /res/drawable-sw360dp/, etc, whatever you can come up with) an xml file that indirectly references the correct resource from the nodpi directory:E.g.

**res/drawable-xlarge-mdpi/my_images.xml**

```
<resources>
    ....
    <item type="drawable" name="one_of_my_images">@drawable/one_of_my_images_large</item>
    ....
</resources>
```

This means that for extra-large mdpi screens, Android will load the 'one_of_my_image_large.png' from the drawable-nodpi directory.

Comment: I want to provide all the resources for every device, also this wouldn't help my problem, because even if i provided only the xhdpi the system would scale it down to hdpi for the tablet anyways

Comment: Ah. You don't want to have an image maintain its size. Instead, you'd like to have an image become larger (in inches) on a *higher density* device? Or do you want an image to become larger (in inches) on a *larger* device?

Comment: I want the image to become larger on large devices, for example, if i have an image that is 10x10px (xhdpi) and it is 7.5x7.5px (hdpi), a tablet will load the hdpi "7.7px" version so it will look small, instead i want it to load the xhdpi "10px" version, so the image will take more space and look larger. so if you take a ruler and measure it on a tablet it must be bigger than on a xhdpi phone. So basically yes in inches it must be bigger.

Comment: That means that your image-size is not related to screen-*density* but is it related to screen-*size* instead. Use the layout-large or layout-xlarge for layouts (or values-large or values-xlarge for dimensions). For larger screens, you make the ImageView (in which you'd show your images) larger (in dips) than for normal screens.

Comment: But by using layout-large or layout-xlarge i would need to create separate files for it, and i don't want that or the size of the app will increase too much, instead of providing additional files i want to redirect it to the xhdpi resources, Basically i need a way to put a "shortcut" inside layout-large and this "shortcut" would redirect it to xhdpi

Comment: Don't worry about the APK size when adding a few extra xml files here and there. They will be compressed and won't add much to your overall APK size (unless you'll have TONs of them or very very very very large ones).

Comment: But if i won't provide the ldpi, mdpi and hdpi assets the phones with those dpis will get scaled assets (which i don't want because i'll get artifacting and some assets are tweaked to display properly) anyway even if i used your method the tablet would scale the xhdpi to hdpi then it would scale it up to fit the value from values-large, everything is displaying properly on phones, the tablets are the problem as they use small resolution assets, i added an image to aid in the description of the problem

Comment: Then you should put your images in drawables-*nodpi* instead so that Android's resource-manager won't scale them up nor down.

Comment: But this way it won't scale it for small devices aswell, so small devices will get huge assets, i would need to do something like this, if deviceSize>5inch then load xhdpi resources, i think there is no other way of doing this if not programmaticly

Comment: Yes, you're right. But you can put all your assets in the *drawable-nodpi* directory and give them different names. E.g. /res/drawable-nodpi/image1_normal.png, /res/drawable-nodpi/image1_xlarge.png, etc. and handle all of the image/drawable selection yourself programmatically or through indirect resource references.

Comment: how did you end up solving this?